# GitLab Pipeline is throwing an Azure CLI error

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, azure-cli, gitlab-pipelines

I'm running a very lightweight GitLab Pipeline which executes a number of Terraform configuration. However, I have hit an absolute roadblock as the pipeline throws an Azure CLI error (screenshot below) when it attempts to run a Terraform init and I simply can't seem to resolve this. Any ideas?

[image]

This error happens at the pipeline stage: `validate`.

Prior to that however, I have another pipeline stage: `deploy` where I am able to install Azure CLI successfully, using the below commands:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  script:
    - curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
```

So after some further investigation, it turns out that this error only occurs when I include my terraform `backend.tf` file which configures an Azure backend for storing my terraform state file. Exclude this file and everything runs smoothly. I'm at a complete loss, as I definitely require that state file in Azure.

**It does appear to me that the Azure CLI successful install at the pipeline `deploy` stage (above) isn't picked up by the Backend.tf configuration.**

Below is the content of my Backend.tf file

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name   = "rg_xxx"
    storage_account_name  = "stxxxxtfstate"
    container_name        = "terraform"
    key                   = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

And below is the YAML snippet from the pipeline `deploy` stage of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file where I call `terraform init` and `apply`.

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:  
    - terraform init
    - terraform plan -var-file=dev-settings.tfvars -out=plan.out
    - terraform apply -auto-approve plan.out
```

Comment: Can you share the YAML for the validate stage, the "terraform init" command, and the contents of your backend.tf file (with any sensitive info redacted)?

Comment: @cdub please see my updated post for the additional details requested. Just to reiterate, if I do exclude or comment out my Backend.tf file, terraform completes successfully. I only get the reported error message when I reinstate the Backend.tf file.

Comment: Is backend.tf the only file in your Terraform configuration that references the azurerm provider?  If yes, is it possible to move the Azure CLI installation step into the same deploy stage as where the terraform commands are being executed -- right before the "terraform init"?   This link shows another way to install Azure CLI in a GitLab pipeline: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/teraform-gitlab-image-no-azure-cli/60534/2

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [**Cdub**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11611377/cdub) for pointing the OP in the right direction. Posted your valuable discussion as an Answer to help other community members.

If the **backend.tf** file references the Azure resource manager provider from the Terraform Configuration, then it's **possible** to move the ***Azure CLI*** installation step into the deploy stage where the terraform commands are being executed right before the **`terraform init`**.

Please refer to [terraform-gitlab-image-no-azure-cli](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/teraform-gitlab-image-no-azure-cli/60534/2) which shows another way to install Azure CLI in a GitHub Pipeline.